# How to color cell during for each looping?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop over a column L in my sheet and then color the cell red if value is not in “big box” and “small box”. The problem is I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong, and VBA is not throwing any errors now.

```
Sub data_validation_from_array()
    Dim packages As Variant
    Dim packages_range As Range
    Dim cell_value As String
    Dim vFilter
    
    Set active_sheet = ActiveSheet
    last_row = active_sheet.Range("L" & active_sheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    Set rng = active_sheet.Range("L2" & last_row)
    
    packages = Array("big box", "small box")
    
    For Each cel In rng
        cell_value = cel.Value
        vFilter = Filter(packages, cell_value, True)
        If Not cell_value = vFilter(i) Then
            cel.Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: what is `i`?  `option explicit` would show that up immediately.

Comment: No errors because the non declared or assigned `i` is given a value of `0` and there is an item at position `0`.  But since you are filtering the array on Cell_Value why would you expect it to ever be different and have the `Not cell_value = vFilter(i)` be anything else but `False`

Comment: Go into `Tools` -> `Options`, then make sure the checkbox for *Require Variable Declarations* is True.  It will help you with some of these typographical errors in the future.

Comment: Ah, I see I have tried the other loop before, but I had a problem making it work, so I tried for each loop instead and the i was leftover from the previous loop and my code become a mess. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Ultimately why not use Conditional formatting?  `=NOT(OR(A1={"big box", "small box"}))`

Comment: It is VBA exercise, this is why I am trying to do it in VBA

Comment: Then: `If Iserror(Application.Match(Cel.value,packages,0)) Then` should be all you need to see if the cell value is in the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub data_validation_from_array()
Dim packages_range As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim last_row As Long

    ' you should use fully qualified reference here
    ' WORKSHEET_NAME: the name of the worksheet where the L column is
    Set active_sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WORKSHEET_NAME")
    
    With active_sheet
        last_row = .Range("L" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set packages_range = .Range("L2", .Cells(last_row, "L"))
    End With
    
    For Each cell In packages_range
        Select Case cell.Value
            Case "big box": cell.Interior.Color = vbRed
            Case "small box": cell.Interior.Color = vbRed
        End Select
    Next cell
    
    Set packages_range = Nothing
    Set cell = Nothing
End Sub
```